# number of ways for 8 people to seat around a square table with 2 numbered seats each

Tags: combinatorics

I know the unnumbered seat version has been asked multiple times, but just a quick check: in this scenario, will it be right to say that the number of ways is $\dfrac{8!}{4}\times 8$, because of first arranging the 8 people and then label the seats? Or is it simply 8! because its 8 people on 8 distinct seats?

Comment: Your second answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Once you number even one seat they are all distinct because of the different distances from the seat you numbered, so there are $8!$ ways of seating them.  You can just imagine lining them up, which you can do in $8!$ ways, then seating them clockwise from the labeled seat.  Each line gives a distinct seating.

Comment: reason i asked this is because when facing a question of making people sitting around a table with numbered seats with certain conditions, the method will be to make them sit without numbered seats while handle the conditions, and then multiply by the total number of seats to account for the numbering. so it doesnt work in the case of first question?

Comment: I don't understand this question.  Unless you use the numbers in your restrictions, once you number one seat they are all distinguishable.  Before you number any seat you can rotate the table at will.  If you have restrictions based on the numbers you need to consider those, but your original question did not.